# async I/O + multithreading (cpu). Парсинг Python

Tags: python, асинхронность

написал парсер.

Для отправки запросов использовал async + aiohttp.

Ответ от сервера складируется в список.

Затем с помощью пула потоков парсим ответы от сервера:

Код:

```
results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines_category = [request(client, url) for url in url_list_category]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_category)
        for item in completed:
            results.append(item.result())

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parsing_category, results):
            pass
```

Вопрос:

Как можно сделать, чтобы при попадании в список, этот элемент сразу обрабатывался пулом потоков?

**Update:**

```
results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines_main_list_category = [parsing_main_list_category(client, url) for url in url_page_category]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_main_list_category)
    #
        coroutines_category = [request(client, url) for url in url_list_category]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_category)
        for item in completed:
            results.append(item.result())

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parsing_category, results):
            pass
    results = []


    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines_main_list_product = [parsing_main_list_product(client, url) for url in url_page_product]
        await asyncio.wait(coroutines_main_list_product)

        coroutines_list_product = [request(client, url) for url in url_list_product]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_list_product)
        for item in completed:
            results.append(item.result())

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parsing_list_product, results):
            pass


    results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines_product = [request(client, url) for url in url_product]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_product)
        for item in completed:
            results.append(item.result())




    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parsing_product, results):
            pass
```

В части

```
coroutines_main_list_category = [parsing_main_list_category(client, url) for url in url_page_category]
            completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_main_list_category)
```

Заполняется url_list_category.

В части:

```
coroutines_main_list_product = [parsing_main_list_product(client, url) for url in url_page_product]
        await asyncio.wait(coroutines_main_list_product)
```

Заполняется url_list_product

А запускаю я этот метод так:

```
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:

    event_loop.run_until_complete(start_main())
finally:

    event_loop.close()
```

**Update 2:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 401, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(url_page_category))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 335, in main
    await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 320, in crawl
    parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future).result())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'result'
```

**Update 3** 
Пробовал `parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, await request_future)`
Выкидывает:

```
future: <Task finished coro=<crawl() done, defined at D:/Git/aquapolis.py:315> exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not iterable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 319, in crawl
    for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in urls]):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Пробовал

```
`parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future).result)`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 401, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(url_page_category))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 335, in main
    await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 320, in crawl
    parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future).result )
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'result'
```

Пробовал

```
parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, await request_future.result())
```

и `parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, await request_future.result())`

```
future: <Task finished coro=<request() done, defined at D:/Git/aquapolis.py:61> exception=RuntimeError('Session is closed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 64, in request
    async with client.get(url, headers=headers) as r:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 855, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 254, in _request
    raise RuntimeError('Session is closed')
RuntimeError: Session is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 401, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(url_page_category))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 335, in main
    await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 320, in crawl
    parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, await request_future.result())
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'result'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one' was never awaited
```

Comment: Попробуйте лучше прочитать документацию к вашей версии Python, чем перебирать варианты наугад. Первый же правильный, просто у вас в `crawl` вместо списка ссылок попадает `None`. Проблему нужно искать в  работе функции `parse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=count_thread) as pool:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        for f in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in url_list_category]):
            loop.run_in_executor(pool, parsing_category, f.result())
```

**UPDATE:** Усложним

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from contextlib import suppress
import os


def parse(page_text):
    urls = []
    # Определяем по разметке на каком типе страниц находимся
    if ...:
        # и извлекаем из неё соответствующие ссылки
        ...
    elif ...:
        ...
    else:
        # или необходимые данные, если это конечная страница парсинга,
        # и что-нибудь с ними делаем
        ...
    return urls


async def crawl(future, client, pool):
    futures = []
    # Получаем из футуры ссылки
    urls = await future
    # Выгребаем для каждой ссылки разметку страницы
    for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in urls]):
        # Передаём парсинг разметки в пул потоков
        parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future).result())
        # Рекурсивно вызываем себя для парсинга новой порции ссылок
        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(crawl(parse_future, client, pool)))
    # Это нужно только для того, чтобы знать
    # когда завершать цикл событий
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)


async def main(root_urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Создаём пул потоков по количеству процессоров
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        # Создаём клиентскую сессию
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            # Создаём корневую футуру
            initial_future = loop.create_future()
            # Помещаем в неё ссылки, с которых начнём парсить
            initial_future.set_result(root_urls)
            # Передаём эту футуру в сопрограмму обхода ссылок
            # вместе с пулом потоков и клиентской сессией
            await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main(['http://www.com']))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Можете прокоментировать последнюю строчку, что это значит. Если можно то вместе 2 последние.

Comment: [as_compeleted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) заворачивает сопрограммы в [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) и возвращает одну за другой по мере их выполнения, а [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) запускает функцию на выполнение в пуле потоков. Все вызовы асинхронные, ничто нигде не блокируется.

Comment: А не подскажите, более сложный пример? Код добавил ниже

Comment: @danilshik подскажу. Правда, подсказываю вам я уже не в первый раз, но ответы мои вы почему-то не принимаете.

Comment: Да уж, усложнили...

Comment: Вопрос: Почему необходимо указывать количество потоков равное количеству процессоров? Потоки же работают в 1 процессоре. . Может вы перепутали с процессами, которые работают эффективно только соразмерно количеству процессоров (с технологией HyberThreading) и имели ProcessorPoolExecutor, а не ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Да и к тому же парсить разные типы страниц в одном методе, как то неправильно. Вот например у меня. 1) парсятся главная страница категорий, определяя количество страниц с категориями 2)парсятся эти страницы, определяя категории; далее идут данные, которые не зависят от категорий, точнее представлен просто список товаров; 3)парсятся страница с товарами, определяя количество страниц с товарами; 4)парсятся все эти страницы, получая список Url на товары; 5) парсятся url товара

Comment: @danilshik количество потоков по количеству процессоров - это стандартная практика. Как показывает опыт, большее число не приводит к большей производительности.

Comment: @danilshik в вашем коде нарушается принцип DRY. В моём функции запросов и парсинга обобщены для лучшей композиции.

Comment: переделываю под ваш пример, возникает ошибка, ошибку добавил

Comment: Посмотрите, что возвращает вам `await request_future`. Возможно, что это уже результат и вызов `result()` не нужен.

Comment: Добавил варианты, которые я испробовал

Comment: не посоветуете, что можно сделать?

Comment: можешь помочь с твоим кодом? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907272/python-error-task-pending-coroutine