# Как спарсить весь текст на веб-странице, включая кнопки, поля, выпадающие списки и т.п?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, lxml

Хочу вытащить абсолютно весь текст с веб-странице, делаю с помощью python + BeautifulSoup + xlmxl.
Сейчас пишу каждый класс, но хочу узнать может как-то можно ускорить процесс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать асинхронность + многопточность. Подробнее об этом - [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899584/async-i-o-multithreading-cpu-%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-python)

Привер кода для реальной задачи -

1.[Пасрер страницы топ игр](https://habr.com/ru/post/319966/)

2.[офф документация питона asyncio(на англиском)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

3.[курс по асинхронности от Олега Молчаного (на русском)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGfv_yRLBiY&list=PLlWXhlUMyooawilqK4lPXRvxtbYiw34S8)